# How do I remesh this model without mass of it spreading out and disintegrating

Tags: sculpting

whenever I add both of them together it turns out like the second picture

also when combined I don't want it to lose detail.

[image]
[image]

[image]

How can I connect this they consist of thousand of faces/vertices with unequal edges.

Comment: Hello what do you mean by adding both of them together?

Comment: like I want both of the pieces to be merged in sculpt mode with the head connected to the body, meaning that everything is gray instead of the head being red.

Comment: also If maybe im just overthinking this process, I decided to casually sculpt with those pieces remaining the same.

Comment: @moonboots can you read this new rephrased question I just made

Comment: you can create a kind of bandage, boolean with the object, then correct in Sculpt mode?